# caret character unexpected behaviour in regular expressions with grep

Tags: command-line, grep

i was running grep commands from "William Shotts" regular expressions example.It seems,the caret character is not doing what it is supposed to do.
I have four test files with all the bin entries in text form.My intention is to find the keywords starting with "zip" from my 4 files(all file names starting with "dirlist"),So ran the command like below:

```
grep '^zip' dirlist*.txt
```

It should return keywords like zip,zipgrep etc but it is not functioning at all.Please help!
What i am doing wrong?

Comment: You should verify the content of the dirlist files first, and provide a minimal example content for the dirlist file if you still have the said problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My intention is to find the keywords starting with "zip"

The caret `^` matches the beginning of a line and **not** the beginning of a word ... Therefore, `grep '^zip' dirlist*.txt` will **only** match `zip` if it's in the beginning of a line.

To match whole words beginning with `zip` anywhere in the line instead, you can use the `-w` option ... from [`man grep`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man1/grep.1.html):

> ```
>    -w, --word-regexp
>           Select only those lines containing matches that form whole words.  The test is that
>           the  matching substring must either be at the beginning of the line, or preceded by
>           a non-word constituent character.  Similarly, it must be either at the end  of  the
>           line  or followed by a non-word constituent character.  Word-constituent characters
>           are letters, digits, and the underscore.
> ```

... and form your RegEx with `zip` followed by zero or more word characters `\w*` like so:

```
grep -w 'zip\w*' dirlist*.txt
```

... or, similarly, use word boundary `\b` instead of `-w` like so:

```
grep '\bzip\w*\b' dirlist*.txt
```

> It should return keywords like zip,zipgrep etc

To return **o**nly the matched part by the RegEx and not the whole line containing the match, you can use `grep`'s option `-o`:

> ```
>    -o, --only-matching
>           Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each such part on
>           a separate output line.
> ```

... like so:

```
grep -ow 'zip\w*' dirlist*.txt
```

... or so:

```
grep -o '\bzip\w*\b' dirlist*.txt
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation!